# Simulate Load Balancing on VMWare?

Tags: load-balancing, vmware-vsphere

Is it possible to simulate a dual load balanced server configuration on VMWare pretty easily?

Is there free load balancing software out there that I could use for this?

I'm using Windows Server Standard 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this done in production using Windows Load Balancing.  It works perfectly - no magic or simulation is required since it works at the OS level.

Answer (score 1):

A good and free load balancing choice is [pen](http://siag.nu/pen/).  If you can access a network port on your VM you can load balance it with pen.  VMWare absolutely supports access to network ports.

Comment: I use pen for load balancing under VMware.  There's a VMware appliance which you can download and push it into VMware.  It takes a little work to get it into ESX.  There's info in the forum about how to do this.  http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/300

Answer (score 0):

Yes, yes you can - depends on your LB mechanism but you can have two VMs pointing their DG at another VM which is acting as a LB (or caching etc.). It wouldn't matter what OS, it's really just a layer 3 thing really.